# the read data value is not passing into Base Class

Tags: constructor, properties, config, read-data

I attempted to read data from the properties file, but I'm facing an issue where the data isn't being successfully passed to the base class. I'm having trouble identifying the specific point where my logic might be lacking.

ReadConfigFile.class & Config Properties (https://i.stack.imgur.com/40JUX.png)
Base Class (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftvdz.png)

The data should be successfully passed into the base class,allowing me to retrieve the URL path from the configuration property file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help understand how you can clarify your question. For example, provide code as text in the question rather than as an image.